# Verify digital signature with ItextSharp

Tags: c#, itext, digital-signature

I'm trying to verify digital signatures in c# using iTextSharp.

I've followed the example in the iText web (http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itextsharp/tutorial/blob/master/signatures/chapter5/C5_03_CertificateValidation/C5_03_CertificateValidation.cs) but the results aren't what I expected. Specifically, when trying to verify a signature through OCSP or CRL, the result usually is that the signature couldn't be verified. I think that shouldn't happen, since Adobe Reader verificates the signatures ok.

The pdf I'm using to test the verification can be found in this link: https://blogs.adobe.com/security/SampleSignedPDFDocument.pdf

This is the code I'm using (short version of the example from the link above):

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    LoggerFactory.GetInstance().SetLogger(new SysoLogger());
    C5_03_CertificateValidation app = new C5_03_CertificateValidation();
    app.VerifySignatures(EXAMPLE); //Pdf file I'm using to test the verification
}

public void VerifySignatures(String path)
{
    Console.WriteLine(path);
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
    AcroFields fields = reader.AcroFields;
    List<String> names = fields.GetSignatureNames();
    foreach (string name in names)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("===== " + name + " =====");
        VerifySignature(fields, name);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

public PdfPKCS7 VerifySignature(AcroFields fields, String name)
{
    PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = fields.VerifySignature(name);
    X509Certificate[] certs = pkcs7.SignCertificateChain;
    DateTime cal = pkcs7.SignDate;

    X509Certificate signCert = certs[0];
    X509Certificate issuerCert = (certs.Length > 1 ? certs[1] : null);
    Console.WriteLine("=== Checking validity of the document at the time of signing ===");
    CheckRevocation(pkcs7, signCert, issuerCert, cal);
    Console.WriteLine("=== Checking validity of the document today ===");
    CheckRevocation(pkcs7, signCert, issuerCert, DateTime.Now);
    return pkcs7;
}

public static void CheckRevocation(PdfPKCS7 pkcs7, X509Certificate signCert, X509Certificate issuerCert, DateTime date)
{
    List<BasicOcspResp> ocsps = new List<BasicOcspResp>();
    if (pkcs7.Ocsp != null)
        ocsps.Add(pkcs7.Ocsp);
    OcspVerifier ocspVerifier = new OcspVerifier(null, ocsps);
    List<VerificationOK> verification =
        ocspVerifier.Verify(signCert, issuerCert, date);
    if (verification.Count == 0)
    {
        List<X509Crl> crls = new List<X509Crl>();
        if (pkcs7.CRLs != null)
            foreach (X509Crl crl in pkcs7.CRLs)
                crls.Add(crl);
        CrlVerifier crlVerifier = new CrlVerifier(null, crls);
        verification.AddRange(crlVerifier.Verify(signCert, issuerCert, date));
    }
    if (verification.Count == 0)
        Console.WriteLine("The signing certificate couldn't be verified with the example");
    else
        foreach (VerificationOK v in verification)
            Console.WriteLine(v);


    //Code not in the example, added by me
    //This way, I can find out if the certificate is revoked or not (through CRL). Not sure if it's the right way though
    if (verification.Count == 0 && pkcs7.CRLs != null && pkcs7.CRLs.Count != 0)
    {
        bool revoked = false;
        foreach (X509Crl crl in pkcs7.CRLs)
        {
            revoked = crl.IsRevoked(pkcs7.SigningCertificate);
            if (revoked)
                break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Is certificate revoked?: " + revoked.ToString());
    }
}
```

And this is the output I get:

```
===== Signature2 =====

=== Checking validity of the document at the time of signing ===
i.t.p.s.OcspClientBouncyCastle INFO  Getting OCSP from http://adobe-ocsp.geotrust.com/responder
iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.OcspClientBouncyCastle ERROR Error en el servidor remoto: (502) Puerta de enlace no válida.
i.t.p.s.OcspVerifier INFO  Valid OCSPs found: 0
i.t.p.s.CrlVerifier INFO  Getting CRL from http://crl.geotrust.com/crls/adobeca1.crl
i.t.p.s.CrlVerifier INFO  Valid CRLs found: 0
The signing certificate couldnt be verified with the example
Is certificate revoked?: False

=== Checking validity of the document today ===
i.t.p.s.OcspClientBouncyCastle INFO  Getting OCSP from http://adobe-ocsp.geotrust.com/responder
iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.OcspClientBouncyCastle ERROR Error en el servidor remoto: (502) Puerta de enlace no válida.
i.t.p.s.OcspVerifier INFO  Valid OCSPs found: 0
i.t.p.s.CrlVerifier INFO  Getting CRL from http://crl.geotrust.com/crls/adobeca1.crl
i.t.p.s.CrlVerifier INFO  Valid CRLs found: 0
The signing certificate couldnt be verified with the example
Is certificate revoked?: False
```

I don't get why the signature couldn't be verified, since Adobe can do it. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: If you look closely at the outputs of Adobe Reader, you'll see "The selected certificate is considered valid because it does not appear in the Certificate Revocation List (CRL) that is **embedded in the signature**." Your code tries to retrieve OCSP responses or CRLs online.

Comment: @mkl I checked and you're right. But the signature also has and OCSP url and a CRL url (I understand that reading the output), I don't understand why the signature couldn't be verified using those. Could it be that the urls aren't valid? Also, I don't get why the crlVerifier didn't give an answer but the crl.IsRevoked did. (btw, thanks for quick answer)

Comment: *"But the signature also has and OCSP url and a CRL url (I understand that reading the output), I don't understand why the signature couldn't be verified using those."* - **A** The OCSP service URL does not exist anymore; the service seems to have been discontinued. That's why one should add validation related information to the PDF itself. **B** The CRL you currently retrieve from that URL is valid from 2015-01-22. The signer certificate is marked valid not after 2009-09-04. thus, no usable information about the certificate can be expected from that CRL. ...

Comment: The CRL embedded into the signature is valid from 2009-07-16 which is the date of the signature creation. That CRL, therefore, does contain usable information about the certificate.

Comment: Hhmmm, I just realized that (even though it is mostly true) the above said does not explain your test results. I'll write up something more detailed later.

Comment: I wanted to write up an answer right now explaining why you do have to check at the time of signing (as documented by the time stamp), but I just realized that your test outputs do not match mine, I get a successful verification in the `Checking validity of the document at the time of signing` section already with the example code. Yours should succeed, too. Which iTextSharp version do you use? I have had success both with 5.5.11 and 5.5.12. Which is your time zone?

Comment: @mkl _"That's why one should add validation related information to the PDF itself."_ I'm sorry, I don't understand what you meant by that.
I hadn't looked at the dates, thanks! But, as you say, I should get the validation at the time of signing, which is not happening.
I was using iTextSharp 5.5.11, I updated it to 5.5.12 but the result stayed the same. My time zone is GMT-3.

Comment: *"I'm sorry, I don't understand what you meant by that."* - Because services providing validation related information (like OCSP services) can go out of business (as you witness here), it makes sense that as early as possible such information are retrieved and added to the PDF itself. *"I should get the validation at the time of signing, which is not happening"* - I'll try to find out why.

Comment: Ok, I ran the code using different system time zones, and indeed: The verification only succeeded in time zones UTC-01 and up, i.e. UTC-01, UTC, UTC+01, ... In particular it is interesting that validation won't work in the time zone the signature has been created in, UTC-04. Thus, there is an issue in the validation code, apparently some datetimes are retrieved respecting the current time zone and some aren't, so comparisons signing time and CRL validity interval sometimes succeed and sometimes not.

Comment: (Alternatively there might be an implied requirement that the time given to `CrlVerifier.Verify` shall be in UTC; in that case some clarification would be required.)

Comment: @mkl Ok, that's strange. When you say there is an issue in the validation code, you mean in the example code or in the iText code (a bug?)?.
On your last comment, I'm not sure if you're asking me if I have a requirement related to the time given to CrlVerifier or if you're wondering if iText has such requirement. If it's the first case, the answer is no, I don't have any requirement like that.

Comment: I meant that the observed behavior (validation succeeds only in some time zones) is either a bug (in iTextSharp) or it indicates that the method `CrlVerifier.Verify` (in iTextSharp) has an undocumented requirement concerning its parameters, a requirement the example code does not fulfill either. Depending on which of both options is correct, your code might be ok or not.

Comment: @mkl Ok, I tested the code same changing `verification.AddRange(crlVerifier.Verify(signCert, issuerCert, date));` to `verification.AddRange(crlVerifier.Verify(signCert, issuerCert, date.ToUniversalTime()));` and it worked! Now the output (of the verification at the time of signing) is: `i.t.p.s.CrlVerifier INFO  Valid CRLs found: 1.
*CERTIFICATE INFO* verified with CrlVerifier: Valid CRLs found: 1`.

Comment: @mkl So I guess that method needs the date to be in UTC. I was having other problems trying to verify signatures (with valid OCSP's not validating), I hope this discovery fixes those problems too.

Comment: That sounds great!

Comment: @mkl It does indeed! Thanks for your help! If I may, I'd like to ask one more question. On your second comment you said that the CRL I was trying to use didn't work because it was valid from a date which was after the expiration of the certificate. Does it also apply to signatures made before the EffectiveDate of the CRL with a non revoked certificate? I mean, if I try to verify a signature at the time of signing of a document I signed yesterday (with a certificate that expires next year) with a CRL that has been updated today, the verification won't be done? Do OCSP's work this way too?

Comment: (Just to clarify, if the above said is true, I would always verify using today's date)

Comment: I will try and create an actual answer, not mere comments.

Comment: I created an answer discussing among other things which CRL one should use. As you mention OCSP: Just like CRLs OCSP responses generated after the validity period of the certificate are not required to indicate a possible revocation. There is an optional extension in OCSP responses, though, with which OCSP responders can indicate how long after the validity period they still do indicate a revocation. Cf. "Archive Cutoff" in RFC 6960.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two aspects to this question:

- Why does iTextSharp appear not to be able to verify the given example signature provided by Adobe?
- At which date, using which CRL, should revocation checks be made?

#### Verifying the given signature using iTextSharp

Using the sample code from [C5_03_CertificateValidation.cs](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I5NS/repos/tutorial/browse/signatures/chapter5/C5_03_CertificateValidation/C5_03_CertificateValidation.cs) the OP couldn't verify that the certificates in question, in particular the signer certificate, was not revoked, neither *"at the time of signing"* nor *"today"*. I, on the other hand, immediately could verify that *"at the time of signing"*.

The major difference between the OP's tests and my tests were that the former ones occurred using the OP's time zone UTC-3 while mine were using UTC+2.

Thus, I ran the code using different system time zones, and indeed: The verification only succeeded in time zones UTC-01 and up, i.e. UTC-01, UTC, UTC+01, ...

The time returned by `DateTime cal = pkcs7.SignDate` in the tests turned out to be given using the current local time zone.

Apparently, therefore, the CRL validation code does *not* use times according to the local time zone but instead in some fixed time zone, presumably in UTC itself.

Thus, one can make the example code work universally by

> changing
>
> ```
> crlVerifier.Verify(signCert, issuerCert, date)
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> crlVerifier.Verify(signCert, issuerCert, date.ToUniversalTime())
> ```

as the OP could confirm after tests.

#### Choosing the right date and CRL for revocation checks

The OP mentions that he would prefer to execute revocation checks using current time and current versions of the CRL of the PKI in question.

While this approach appears to make use of the most up-to-date information available, its usefulness is limited:

- If the certificate under scrutiny is beyond its original validity period now (i.e. its valid-not-after date is in the past) but was not at the time of signing, information about its possible revocation at the time of signing may not be on the CRL anymore. Indeed, according to RFC 5280

  > An entry MUST NOT be removed
  >   from the CRL until it appears on one regularly scheduled CRL issued
  >   beyond the revoked certificate's validity period.

  By implication, therefore, it *may* be removed from the CRL in any version issued *after* the validity period.

  Thus, it makes no sense to use a CRL newer than the end of the validity period of the certificate.
- Even if the certificate under scrutiny is not yet beyond its original validity period, the PKI provider might have gone out of business. In that case all access points for revocation information now might only serve a final version of the CRL created when the PKI was still active or none at all.

  In that case one can use that final CRL or the newest CRL one still has available (e.g. in some CRL cache) as long as the CRL is recent enough.

Thus, validation policies often allow and even require the use of an older CRL as long as it is recent enough, at least the CRL's `nextUpdate` value must be after the signing time, and at the same time old enough, at least the CRL's `thisUpdate` value must be before the end of the validity period of the certificate.

One item to consider, though, is what one considers to be the signing time to compare with when checking whether an older CRL can be used.

The `pkcs7.SignDate` used in the iText example code above may merely be the content of a field in the PDF or the CMS container which might have been faked: Someone might have gotten hold of the private key; after the associated certificate has been revoked, that person might still misuse the key setting the signing time information to a date before revocation.

Thus, you might determine the signing date differently. E.g.

- if the signature container contains a signature time stamp or the PDF document contains a later document time stamp, and if that time stamp can be trusted, the time of that time stamp can be used;
- if the signed document has been locally stored for some time (e.g. in some archiving system) and the time of storage is known and can be trusted, that time can be used;
- ...

Comment: I would prefer to execute revocation checks using current time and current versions of the CRL because (on my scenario) the CRL verifier won't find any usefull CRL's at the time of signing. Could it be possible that the CRL that the verifier is retrieving can't be used to verify signatures  at their time of signing? The CRL 'ThisUpdate' value is today and the 'NextUpdate' is tomorrow. (I don't see any parameter that tells from which date the CRL is valid, that's why I think maybe I can't use that CRL to verify using an old date).

Comment: @jbac *"Could it be possible that the CRL that the verifier is retrieving can't be used to verify signatures at their time of signing?"* - Indeed, as you can read in my answer: All revocation information about a certificate may be dropped from any CRL published *after* the original validity period of that certificate ends. Thus, if you want to verify signatures like the example signature you gave, you have to use older CRLs.

Comment: @jbac On the other hand, if you only want to verify signatures whose signer certificate is still valid at verification time, you can (and should) use the most current CRL (or request an OCSP response just in time). In that case, though, your choice of example PDF was not appropriate... ;)

Comment: Yes, my bad, I was referring to the case when the signing certificate is still valid. Sorry I didn't clear that up, clearly that isn't the case of the example pdf. So, if I wanted to create a generic solution for both cases (the certificate could still be valid or not), I should check first if it's still valid and in consecuence of that verify the signature using the time of signing or today's date?