# How to verify that a pdf file contains a valid digital signature?

Tags: c#, itext

I have a pdf that has been digitally signed and I would like to check if:

1) the pdf contains a signature

2) if the signature is valid

I have already tried some code using the iTextSharp library, but without success. Place one of the solutions I've tried, but without success. Particularly when I check on names.Count, it succeeds and immediately returns false. I am attaching a screen to read AcroFields, I don't know if it can help to understand the problem. I can't get out of it.

[image] [image]

```
public static bool ValidateFileSignatures(byte[] file)
{

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file);

    AcroFields af = reader.AcroFields;
    var names = af.GetSignatureNames();
    if (names.Count == 0)
        return false; // no signatures

    foreach (string name in names)
    {
        if (!af.SignatureCoversWholeDocument(name))
        {
            return false;
        }

        PdfPKCS7 pk = af.VerifySignature(name);


        if (!pk.Verify())
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The sample PDF can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g95ou9lbf4kcqg7/AADgmkv1YpOri3S3g2YIUZa2a?dl=0)

I also found another solution that uses the Pknet library, but I couldn't find the NuGet package. Any solution or suggestion is welcome. Thank you

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46602020) answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Verify digital signature with ItextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452171/verify-digital-signature-with-itextsharp)

Comment: What flavor of "valid" are you after exactly? Just mathematically valid, i.e.  correct hash values? Or also valid in some specific legal context, with revocation checks etc.?

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by "but without success"? Didn't compile? Runtime errors? Unexpected result?

Comment: With revocation checks etc. @mkl

Comment: First of all, please share your test PDF in question. According to what you say, it appears that there are no (non-empty) AcroForm signature fields in it. Are you sure your PDF is signed using a regular AcroForm signature field? Or is it probably some proprietary mechanism like a XFA signature?

Comment: How can I share the pdf?  @mkl

Comment: Usually one uploads the file to a public file sharing service, e.g. using public shares on google drive or drop box, definitively not some service drowning us in ads, and then you post the URL here.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g95ou9lbf4kcqg7/AADgmkv1YpOri3S3g2YIUZa2a?dl=0 @mkl Thank you.

Comment: @Elmoro - I have proposed an [edit] to your question where I included the link you provided.  Please, in the future, only [edit] your question to add any relevant details or data.  Comments are much more difficult to find the necessary info to help answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the title of your question you ask for a way *to verify that a pdf file **contains** a valid digital signature*.

The example file you provided, though, is **not** a *pdf file containing a digital signature*; it's the other way around, it is a *signature container containing a PDF as its embedded signed data*!

Thus, it is not surprising that iText tells you (by means of `af.GetSignatureNames().Count == 0`) that the PDF does not contain any signatures because it really doesn't.

To check whether you have a PDF signed like this, you don't need a PDF library like iText but a different kind of library / API, a library that can inspect the contents and verify the signatures of a CMS signature container, e.g. BouncyCastle for a first, simple validation or eSignature DSS for an EU qualified signature validation.

---

For backgrounds on PDFs with embedded signatures see [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096).

---

Considering your example signature you might be interested in validation according to European qualified signature legislation.

One publicly available validator implementation for this is the [CEF Digital Signature Services](https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/wiki/display/CEFDIGITAL/DSS). There is a [demo web application](https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/DSS/webapp-demo/validation) for validating using this software.

DSS is written in Java but you can run it as a service you communicate with via REST. This should allow for an easy integration with .Net code, too.

If that is an option for you, simply use the demo web application to validate your test cases and check whether the results match your expectations. E.g. your example file is validated as TOTAL_PASSED. (In my eyes it is a bit critical that the OCSP response for the signer certificate is signed using SHA1withRSA/2048.)

If that isn't an option for you, you can still checkout the project on [github](https://github.com/esig/dss) to get an idea of a full blown signing and signature validation service.

If the required validation profile differs, please clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the example you posted helps me a little. I would need at least a proposal for a possible solution.

Comment: *"the example you posted helps me a little"* - It should help you as far as to see that your whole approach to this was wrong: You originally thought you had to find and verify an integrated PDF signature and now you know that this is not the case. Thus, you can start to look for verification solutions for generic CMS signature containers (with embedded signed data).