# Create Signature field on PDF iTextSharp. How automatically save PDF after user signed

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation, digital-signature

I created pdf by iTextSharp 5.5.13. I have Signature field on the PDF. I need When user signed the signature field, the pdf will be automatically save on specific path (e.g. "c:/signed/pdf11.pdf"). Is is possible?

My code:

```
PdfFormField field = PdfFormField.CreateSignature(pdfWriter);
field.SetWidget(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_NONE);
field.FieldName = name;
field.Flags = PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT;
field.SetPage();
field.MKBorderColor = iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK;
field.MKBackgroundColor = iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;

PdfAppearance tp1 = PdfAppearance.CreateAppearance(pdfWriter, width, height);
tp1.Rectangle(0.5f, 0.5f, width - 0.5, height - 0.5);
tp1.Stroke();
field.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, tp1);
pdfWriter.AddAnnotation(field);
```

Comment: Yes that is quite possible. After you added the signature save the document to a folder of your liking...

Comment: I need the document to save (or copy) itself to some path. Exist some event after user signed? Do have some sample?

Comment: You supplied too little information to answer that question. How does the signing take place? Do you have an application where the user can sign the signature? Or does the user use some other tool/Application to sign? Describe your setting in more detail and we might be able to help you...

Comment: I don't have any application. Just pdf document. User open the pdf document in some reader and signed it. I need event (document signed) and then save (or copy) the document to another path in local network (directory for signed documents).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to prepare the document so that after a user signed it in an interactive PDF viewer (in particular Adobe Acrobat, I assume), the document automatically is saved to a fixed path. As far as I know this is not possible using mechanisms from the PDF specification. Probably you can do that using JavaScript but my JS-Fu is severely limited, so I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a weird setup but ok lets see: The so called event you are looking for is (I assume) that the user stores the signed file into some network folder.

Write a program which checks the network folder's content for new files. If there is one load it and check whether it has been signed. If so save it to the path you want.

There are plenty examples how to check if a document has been signed e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452171).